# Import Activity Task on the test account CM 2.0 Test Account 2

Tags: marketing-cloud, import

We had enable Import activity in our account last week but as mentioned in the following documentation
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/

I could not see any option **Interaction -> Activities -> Import**

Instead I saw this option 
**Interaction -> Import -> Activities -> Import**

Is this the same as mentioned above  ?

In this section I could not see some options that was mentioned in the documentation.

For example it is mentioned that you will have option of choosing Salesforce Data Source Type in the file location drop down  instead I saw only the “Enhanced FTP option” is available.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing.  Make sure to check out [File Transfer Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/file_transfer_activity/) as they are often used in conjunction.

Comment: I tried creating an import activity and selected a list (suppression list). After that I uploaded the file to the FTP location. The Import activity ran but it did not populate the list that I had specified instead it created a csv file outside the Import folder in the FTP folder. Am I doing something wrong here? I though the List that I specified might have got populated.

Comment: Trying running  File Transfer Activity first, then do the import activity.